# How can I tell when a React AG-Grid component is done rendering its data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to automatically resize my columns to fit their contents using an `autoSizeAll` function I wrote. I want this to happen every time the grid's data is done rendering. This is because the user can click a 'get data' button that re-populates the grid with different data at any point in time.

[image]

My `autoSizeAll` function works on its own, but I am having an issue of calling it too early (before the data is done rendering), resulting in weird/no column autosizing.

Someone was able to help me get it to work by using `setTimeout` with an arbitrary time, but this seems like a solution that isn't completely reliable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (rowData && rowData.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => autosizeAll(), 250)
  }
}, [columnDefs, rowData, autoSizeAll])
```

So the question is: **Is there a way I can reliably check if the grid has rendered its data?** AG-Grid's `firstDataRendered` event works perfectly for the first render but doesn't trigger after that. I have also tried `onRowDataUpdated` as well as not using the timeout, but the autosizing seems to trigger before the data is done rendering, sizing the columns in a weird way.

[image]

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks :)

**Edit:** Here is the code for `autoSizeAll`:

```
const autoSizeAll = useCallback(() => {
    const allColumnIds = [];
        gridRef.current.columnApi.getColumns().forEach((column) => {
            allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
        });
    
        gridRef.current.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);

}, []);
```

Comment: Still after? :)

Comment: Haha yes, I have not had any luck so far

Comment: I have found a way to use onRowDataUpdated event. Please check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lhh50xmK6A7s2TcG?preview

Answer (score 0):

you can use the AG-Grid event: `gridReady`. The `gridReady` event runs once the grid is fully initialized and ready to be interacted with.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const YourGridComponent = ({ columnDefs, rowData, autoSizeAll }) => {
  const agGridRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rowData && rowData.length > 0) {
      // Resize columns after the grid is ready
      agGridRef.current.api.addEventListener('gridReady', () => {
        autoSizeAll();
      });
    }
  }, [rowData, autoSizeAll]);

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        ref={agGridRef}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        rowData={rowData}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourGridComponent;
```

If you have any question or this doesn't work, comment below. Hope this helps.

Comment: According to the AG Grid documentation (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/), the gridReady event corresponds to: "The grid has initialised and is ready for most api calls, but may not be fully rendered yet". I still gave it a try, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey, please try to change 'gridReady' with 'rowDataUpdated'

Comment: Yup I've tried rowDataUpdated as well - sometimes it waits until the data is rendered and autosizes correctly, but most of the time it tries to autosizes early (before rowData.length > 0) and the columns don't autosize correctly. If I keep the if ( rowData && rowData.length > 0), then it doesn't autosize because it runs autoSizeAll before rowData is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

AgGridReact have a props processRowPostCreate which takes a callback

```
<AgGridReact 
    processRowPostCreate={() => {
      console.log("this is called after the table is rendered ===>")
    }} 
    rowData={rowData} 
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
  />
```

Can you please try calling your custom function autosizeAll from here and see if it works?
Also definition of autosizeAll would help debug this issue more.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it isn't working,  just like rowDataUpdated. It doesn't seem to actually wait until the grid is rendered, for whatever reason

Comment: can you provide the details of this function - autosizeAll?

Comment: Sure thing!

I added it to the end of the post/question.

Comment: @WesternCreamCheese added another answer. it is fully tested and working on my end. Please upvote it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Trying again :)

To get notified by onRowDataUpdated event, we should update our data using [applyTransaction](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-transactions/)

Put this as a prop in your AgGridReact component

```
onRowDataUpdated={() => autoSizeAll()}
```

Update your data using applyTransaction like below

```
  const updateItems = useCallback(() => {
    // update the first 2 items
    const itemsToUpdate = [];
    gridRef.current.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function (
      rowNode,
      index
    ) {
      // only do first 2
      if (index >= 2) {
        return;
      }
      const data = rowNode.data;
      data.price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000 + 20000);
      itemsToUpdate.push(data);
    });
    const res = gridRef.current.api.applyTransaction({ update: itemsToUpdate });
    printResult(res);
  }, []);
```

By this way, you ensure your grid is going to be resized after you update your data

Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1xcD5c6IKlSTOhpo?preview

Hit on Update Top 2, see the grid resize and start digging through :D

Comment: Hi Ahmet, thanks for digging deeper into this! My only concern is that clicking 'get data' doesn't modify existing cell values - it completely re-renders a new grid. The rows and columns can also be different. Therefore I'm not sure I can use applyTransaction with update in my case

Answer (score 0):

We need to modify the autoSizeAll first.

```
const autoSizeAll = useCallback(() => { 
    const allColumnIds = []; 
    gridRef.current.columnApi.getColumns().forEach((column) => { allColumnIds.push(column.colId); }); 
    gridRef.current.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds); 
    var params = {
      force: true,
    };
    gridRef.current.api.refreshCells(params);

}, []);
```

And then implement the component as below -

```
<AgGridReact 
    ref={gridRef}
    rowData={rowData} 
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    onRowDataUpdated={autoSizeAll}
  />
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Just tried this - unfortunately it seems to not work most of the time, just like before when I used onRowDataUpdated. I'm starting to suspect maybe I'm not interacting with the grid correctly? Could you share the whole file you're using?

Comment: @WesternCreamCheese, sure thing. here is a public gist - https://gist.github.com/khan-shazid/7a4229b3053ad4e0d6003832466d1eb7

copy AgGridReactSample.jsx file to App.jsx and run. let me know if there is any difficulties. Also it would be great if you could provide the Get Data button method details.